# Configuration for Vyatta upgrade in SL

Tags: ibm-cloud-infrastructure

I am implementing an upgrade HA using Java API after purchasing a Vyatta.
Can you provide me with any sample code or guide to implement Upgrade HA of Vyatta ? What configuration is mandatory to set in ordering the upgrade ??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a Rest example that can help you:

```
https://[username]:[apikey]@api.softlayer.com/rest/v3/SoftLayer_Product_Order/verifyOrder

Note: Once ready your configuration, change from `verifyOrder` to `placeOrder`

Method: POST

Json Payload:

{
  "parameters": [
    {
      "orderContainers": [
        {
          "location": "AMSTERDAM",
          "complexType": "SoftLayer_Container_Product_Order_Hardware_Server_Gateway_Appliance",
          "packageId": 174,
          "clusterResourceId": 61500,    // Gateway Id
          "prices": [
            {
              "id": 74865   // Single Intel Xeon E3-1270 (4 Cores, 3.40 GHz)
            },
            {
              "id": 21010  // 4 GB DDR3 1333
            },
            {
              "id": 36044  // Vyatta 6.x Subscription Edition (64 bit)
            },
            {
              "id": 876 //Non-RAID
            },
            {
              "id": 1267  // 500 GB SATA
            },
            {
              "id": 342 // 20000 GB Bandwidth
            },
            {
              "id": 273  //100 Mbps Public & Private Network Uplinks
            },
            {
              "id": 17129  // 1 IPv6 Address
            },
            {
              "id": 55  // Host Ping
            },
            {
              "id": 58 //Automated Notification
            },
            {
              "id": 420  // Unlimited SSL VPN Users & 1 PPTP VPN User per account
            },
            {
              "id": 418  //Nessus Vulnerability Assessment & Reporting
            },
            {
              "id": 21  // 1 IP Address
            },
            {
              "id": 57  // Email and Ticket
            },
            {
              "id": 906  //Reboot / KVM over IP
            }
          ],
          "hardware": [
            {
              "domain": "mydomain.com",
              "hostname": "myhostname"
            }
          ]
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

Where:

**clusterResourceId:** Used to identify which gateway is being upgraded to HA.

To get valid item prices for package 174, please execute:

```
https://[username]:[apikey]@api.softlayer.com/rest/v3/SoftLayer_Product_Package/174/getItemPrices?objectMask=mask[id,locationGroupId,item[id,keyName,description],pricingLocationGroup[locations[id, name, longName]]]

Method: GET
```

**Reference:**

[SoftLayer_Container_Product_Order_Hardware_Server_Gateway_Appliance](http://sldn.softlayer.com/reference/datatypes/SoftLayer_Container_Product_Order_Hardware_Server_Gateway_Appliance)